# Filter boolean data on SSRS 2008 chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm having a hard time applying a filter on a 3D pie chart using 3 columns from my sql script:

- column 1 will count the amount of terminals in  the field
- column 2 will show the terminal model (I've 4 types of model)
- column 3 will be used as a filter to display if the terminal is active or not (this is a boolean data type , I've tried with 1 and 0 but it did not work).

I'm now applying the filter to display only active terminals by saying that my column 3 must be equal to "true" but when I run the preview , the chart only display 1 type of "terminal model" with the wrong count of terminals)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66I3A.png)

Using any other column on the filter works fine but I need the column with the Boolean values.

I have not find videos on youtube talking about adding filters to charts on ssrs 2008

Comment: The Like operator is for string, you must use equals (=)

Comment: I've tried =True or =False but is not working . I've tried with all relational symbols too.

Comment: I used another type of chart to accomplish what I was looking for